# How do I send a graphQL query that contains an extended query?

Tags: python-3.x, graphql, apollo-server, graphene-python

I have an graphene.ObjectType model on one of my services which extends a definition in another service

```
@extend(fields="id")
class ExtendedProtectedObject(graphene.ObjectType):
    id = external(graphene.ID(required=True))
    additional_color = graphene.String()

    class Meta:
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)

    def resolve_additional_color(self, info):
        return "blue"

    @staticmethod
    def _ExtendedProtectedObject__resolve_reference(root, info):
        # root is an instance of self class with id set to the query id value
        return root
```

We run Apollo Federation to combine all of our graphql schemas in onle location and to route queries/mutations etc.
What query can I add as a unit test in my service which mirrors what Apollo does when I request on my additionalColor field?
For example this query:

```
query getExtendedProtectedObject($id: ID!) {
    extendedProtectedObject(id: $id) {
        additionalColor
    }
}
```

What query does federation forward on to my service?
I want to use that query in one of my unit tests in my service because it calls the ExtendedProtectedObject method _ExtendedProtectedObject__resolve_reference before hitting any field resolvers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can do this with this query:

```
query ($representations:[_Any!]!) {
    _entities(representations:$representations) {
        ...on ExtendedProtectedObject {
            additionalColor
        }
    }
}
```

and use these query variables:

```
variables=dict(
    representations=[{"__typename": "ExtendedProtectedObject", "id": to_global_id("ExtendedProtectedObject", 1)}],
)
```

Per [the Apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/federation/federation-spec/#resolve-requests-for-entities)

#### Validation Errors Returned Client Side For Above Query

Just a heads up, when I tried to submit that query from a client, it fails an Apollo server validation step. Under the hood federation will send this query to your service when a normal query is sent in which requires resolving fields in an extended ObjectType.

#### Security Implication If Validation Off + Query Can Hit Service

So if you have validation turned off one could use this query to target a response to only one of your services. If validation is turned off, for a type like Me this could be a security vulnerability if this query can be successfully executed by a client. This is because it would allow a query to set an external global id and hit a service directly, circumventing the source of the Me get_node and Me.resolve_id, and instead only hit Me._Me__resolve_reference and any service specific resolvers. This assumes that id is the only key field.